# Criando propriedades em todas as janelas WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Alguém tem alguma ideia se é possível herdar da classe Window do WPF, criar algumas propriedades e quando for criar as minhas telas ao invés de fazer elas herdarem de Window fazer com que herdem dessa classe criada ?

Um exemplo:

Tenho um método que faz o carregamento de uma lista de arquivos no banco; para a tela não ficar estática eu passo a referência do form para o método e vou alterando a propriedade que faz o binding com a Progressbar conforme o andamento da operação.

O problema é que esse método é usado por mais de uma tela e como a classe Window não possuí a propriedade de binding com a Progressbar para que funcione o método eu preciso referenciar o form específico, a questão é que se eu tiver 10 forms que usem esse método precisaria ter 10 chamadas diferentes para ele para tratar cada um individualmente.

Tentei passar a Window como referência para depois pegar o Name do Form, porém não funciona, alguém conhece algum outro jeito de fazer e/ou uma maneira de criar uma classe abstrata que herdasse de Window e adicionasse as propriedades que preciso? Assim quando fosse passar a referência passava esta classe abstrata que teria as propriedades.

Tentei também passar a propriedade por referência, mas o Visual Studio diz que não é possível passar uma propriedade por referência.

Comment: Você quer ter uma propriedade padrão em todas as janelas. Isso?

Comment: Exatamente.....

Comment: Bem, a parte de tu ter uma classe base eu entendi e funciona, sim. Eu só fiquei confusa com o exemplo. Tu tem um método que retorna uma lista de objetos, isso? E aí tu tem na window um progress q vai atualizando de acordo com o retorno desse método, isso? É isso que tu quer tornar genérico? Esse progress?

Comment: Não, eu tenho um método que recebe uma lista de arquivos e salva eles no banco, o retorno dele é uma classe que contém um bool indicando se houve erro e uma lista com as mensagens do erro (No caso de existirem os erros). Junto com a lista de arquivos eu passo o form e dentro do meu loop que insere no banco eu atualizo o progresso da progressbar, ex: Form.ValorProgressBar = (100 * i ) / Arquivos.Count;

Comment: E eu queria tornar genérico essa propriedade para eu poder colocar a classe genérica como referência na assinatura no método e consequentemente usar a propriedade independente de qual form eu passe.